# What is the true meaning of Never consider yourself the cause of the results of your activities

Tags: bhagavad-gita

In verse 2.47 **Lord Krishna** says **Never consider yourself the cause of the results of your activities**.
So according to this verse if Person A kills Person B then person A, is not the cause of person B's death and will not be punished.

Comment: This is wrong understanding of teachings. He says Atma our reality is non doer and actions are done in realm of nature. Therefore, he says realize your essence of Atman which is beyond karma. But in relative level, this cannot be applied as such.

Comment: In level of world all actions have consequences which is inevitable and the knowledge of Atman cannot be directly applied here.

Comment: BG 2.47 is reg. the attitude with which the prescribed duty needs to be performed, (for Karmanyeva may not connote a prohibited action),also in cont., next verse 2.48 suggests (yoga-sthaḥ kuru karmāṇi, action established in yog), is to ascend to the yoga of wisdom (2.49).,(for an aspirant seeking progress). bcos, the knowledge about the Self (sankhya yog) is already imparted by the Lord in prev. verses.So here the very intention to kill, does not qualify a Person A, to be in the context of teachings of BG as A can't find any unity of purpose with  these teachings aligned to his intentions.

Answer (score 2):

***Lord Krishna says Never consider yourself the cause of the results of your activities***.

It has very scientific meaning so read some examples here:

***Example 01***

When you say, I work for 10 hours on the computer then it means that your neurons of the brain and the muscles of your finger and hand works for 10 hours.

***You can't claim that you are a neuron or you are a muscle.***

***EXAMPLE 02***

When you say, i climbed the mount Everest then it means that your muscles Leg, your brain determination, and your lungs work there but ***You can't claim that you are lungs, muscles of Leg, etc..***

**Conclusion**: So here Krishna trying to dissolve ***I*** means ***ego*** that you have work but in reality, many things work there and you can't claim that ***those many things means you***.

**EDIT:-**

REFERENCE: ALSO SEE THE VIEW OF ASTAVAKRA GITA:

> प्रकृते: क्रियमाणानि गुणै: कर्माणि सर्वश: | अहङ्कारविमूढात्मा कर्ताहमिति मन्यते || Chapter 3, verse 27||
>
> ***A egotist, under the influence of the three modes of material nature-Rajas, Sattva and Tamas, thinks himself to be the doer of
> activities, which are in actuality carried out by nature.***

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok I will edit with the information in minutes

Comment: Both examples involve 'good' work. Could you extend this for if someone commits a bad deed?